# Logical OR doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a literal object `obj`. My problem is when I'm to iterate by obj, I see in console all value of keys i.e. name, age, status and address. What's wrong with my `if` statement?

```
var obj = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 25,
    status: 'active',
    address: 'NYC, 45th St., 234512'
};

for (var elem in obj) {
    if (elem != 'name' || elem != 'age') {
        var val = obj[elem];
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a hilarious title. I get the feeling logical or works just fine in JS, and you've made a mistake somewhere. See [the first rule of debugging](http://e-mats.org/2008/10/the-first-rule-of-debugging/)

Answer (score 7):

It should be logical `AND`, not `OR`:

```
if (elem != 'name' && elem != 'age') { ... }
```

... literally meaning if `elem` is not `"name"` **AND** `elem` is not `"age"` then show the value.

Comment: Oh, yes. Of cause. Sorry :)

Comment: Wouldn't that be checking the *value* of each element in the object? None of the elements in that example contain the value 'name' or age...

Comment: @Digital_Utopia - `elem` is the key, not the value.

Comment: @Digital_Utopia Nope. `for .. in` loop iterates the keys in the object.